# Another question about showing that a point is not an accumulation point of a given set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

> Let $C = \{ (\frac 1n , \frac mn) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :  m,n \in \mathbb Z , n \neq 0 \} $.

I'm trying to argue that each point not on the $y$-axis is not an accumulation point of $C$. Is this verbal argument valid?

> For each point $p$ not on the $y$-axis, let $\epsilon$ be the shortest
>   of the distances to the nearby points in $C$. Then the punctured
>   $\epsilon$-ball about $p$ contains no point of $C$ because $\frac 1n$
>   is not dense in $\mathbb R$.  That is, $p$ is not an accumulation
>   point of C.

Comment: I think you can be explicit about what the shortest distance should be.  You'd like to be able to say, for one, that this distance isn't 0.  You might want to look at something like the $x$-value of the point divided by 4.  Edit: or 2, as an answer below notes.  :)

Comment: @Ryan: Hi Ryan, this is another example where you have to look very specifically at your set. For example if instead we consider the set $D=\{\left(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{m}{k}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^2: n, m, k\in\mathbb{Z}, n, k\neq0\}$. Can you see the difference between these sets? If you consider this set then the corresponding statement is no longer true. In particular every point of $D$ is a limit point of $D$. So to prove the statement you have to crucially use the definition of $C$ in a nontrivial way.

Comment: @OwenSizemore Yes I see the difference, and wish I was working with your easier example instead! What's troubling me about my example is that the two coordinates are related (y is not an arbitrary rational but one that depends on x by n); this makes it so tedious and frustrating to exhibit epsilon in a way that does not involve introducing several more variables and tedious conditions and splitting up $p$ into its coordinates.

Comment: @Ryan: Yes the easiest way I can see is to take a point (x, y) and break into two cases. I) when x is of the form $\frac{1}{n}$, and II.) when it is not.

Comment: @owen Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $\epsilon$ be the shortest of the distances to the nearby points in $C$.

If you've established that there exists a shortest such distance, then you are done! So a sentence like this belongs at the end of the proof, not in the middle. To find the closest nearby points, you may want to reason by considering the $x$-coordinate of $p$, and considering

$$\min_{c\in C,} { \{ |p_x - c_x| \} },$$

with a special case for if $p_x = 1/n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks, I've got so many questions: 1) how about the y-coordinate? 2) doesnt "nearby points" already mean that i'm not considering any point of C that coincides with $p$, i.e., that the distance is non-zero ? 3) Is the part of my given argument where I wrote "because $\frac 1n$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$" logical?    Thanks!

Comment: 1. My idea was to first look at the $x$-coordinate...if it has a nonzero minimum, then we're done (since the total distance is bounded below by the distance in the $x$ coordinate). If $p_x = 1/n$ for some $n$ we can make a special case of that. 2. I would specify that that's what you mean, since I haven't heard this use of "nearby points" before 3. The $\mathbb{Z}^+$ was a mistake...should have written $\mathbb{Z}$. :)  4. I don't see what you're saying with this sentence. You are correct that it's not dense, but I don't see the relevance.

Comment: Can you believe that this is from a larger question asking for C's accumulation points and isolated points. I've happily shown that the the set of accum points contain the y-axis, I'm now trying to show the set of accum points is precisely the y-axis, and then it will follow that the set of isolated points are precisely C. All this for a question that's worth _three_ measly marks.